# Static LAN IP Problems on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server

I'm having problem on defining static IP to my machine. I want to declare a static IP which connects to router with wireless, those lines below are the settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.106
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 77.88.8.8 77.88.8.1
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.255.255
    wpa-ssid <my-ssid>
    wpa-psk <psk-generated-with-wpa_passphrase>
```

It defines the static IP, yet I cannot connect to internet with those settings. Is there any problem with configuration?

#### Edit

It did not work without `broadcast` and `network` either.

Comment: You should not have to define `network` or `broadcast`, I believe... is there a reason you included these?  (It may be breaking things).  This will also break any attempts to use other wireless networks, as you would have to change `/etc/network/interfaces` for all other wireless networks.  You should also be using Network Manager for static IP configuration, if you are on a GUI Ubuntu installation

Comment: Yes, I am on GUI, however GUI Network Manager does not also do well, the same happens. || I just looked up an online tutorial-like thing and included `broadcast` and `network`, it had not worked without them either.

Comment: Then you probably did something wrong - and most 'online tutorials' are not authoritative references.  So, following the steps [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/729200/setting-up-static-ip-address-for-wireless-in-ubuntu-14-04/729250#729250) will help you with the GUI portion - that should help with configuration.  If it still doesn't work on your network, then you probably didn't set things up right anyways.  Why do you need static, though?  Is DHCP not enough for your environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should have more success by assigning a static IP address for your machine through your router software as opposed to assigning from Ubuntu.

This works fine on our configuration.